# R 3.6.1; Ubuntu, trying to update the packages of Bioconductor and a get an error: .... installation path not writeable, unable to update packages

Tags: ubuntu, bioconductor

Unable to completely install and update the 'Bioconductor base packages' in Ubuntu.

I am trying to update the core packages of Bioconductor, but I get an error:

> Using Bioconductor 3.7 (BiocInstaller 1.30.0), R 3.6.1 (2019-07-05).
>   installation path not writeable, unable to update packages: abind,
>   acepack,askpass, assertthat, backports, base64enc, BH, bitops, broom,
>   carData, caTools, cellranger, cli, clipr, colorspace, crayon,...

In order to update I tried the following code:

```
biocLite()
```

I also tried:

```
biocLite("BiocUpgrade")
```

Any option was unsuccessful.

After visiting and reviewing the documentation of Bioconductor [http://bioconductor.org/install/] I would expect to update without problems and hoped to get a message like:

> Using Bioconductor version All packages updated...

But instead I got:

> Using Bioconductor 3.7 (BiocInstaller 1.30.0), R 3.6.1 (2019-07-05).
>   installation path not writeable, unable to update packages: abind,
>   acepack,askpass, assertthat, backports, base64enc, BH, bitops, broom,
>   carData, caTools, cellranger, cli, clipr, colorspace, crayon,...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you in linux or windows or OS X?

Comment: You seems to have installed R as sudo perhaps ... you should install locally. And anyway R's version and packages change so quickly leading to many updating and upgrading problems - I would heavily recommend you to instal conda (a universal package manager and virtual environment manager), create a new conda environment and install there the stuff. bioconda solves many problems you can have during installations. -

Comment: I am on Linux. I will try the recommendation that you provided. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
####################
# install miniconda
####################
# if in linux
# if 64 bit
cd ~/
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
# if 32 bit
cd ~/
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86.sh
bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86.sh
# follow the instructions - whereby install it locally in home.
```

After successful installation, your bash now recognizes all `conda` commands.

```
############################
# create new environment for your R version
############################

conda create --name R361

############################
# enter the create environment by
############################

conda activate R361
# shell begins now always with (R361)...$ 
# to show you in which environment you are

############################
# Install your desired R version
############################

conda install -c bioconda R=3.6.1   

# -c bioconda means: look into bioconda repository for this package
# commonly used other repositories are: -c anaconda
#                                       -c conda-forge
```

If you just do:

```
# conda install r-base # or: conda install -c conda-forge r-base
# or: conda install -c bioconda r-base  or: conda install -c r r-base
# very likely it installs newest R.
# with R=3.6.1 you can control exactly which version should be installed.
```

I personally try first `-c bioconda` for all bioinformatics relevant stuff.
because bioconda ist very up to date for R packages in general.
(well, I am bioinformatician, too ;) - so I have experience with this).

```
############################
# biocLite() is now old. Install BiocManager 
############################

# Start R
R

# install BiocManager
> install.packages("BiocManager")
> require(BiocManager) # or: libary(BiocManager)

# in BiocManager `install()` is like former `biocLite()` install command
> install("<your bioconductor package>")
```

Some bioconductor packages require additional non-R packages to be installed.
When working globally, these are the `sudo apt install r-cran-*` candidates.
However, google for "conda install " and you will find
then which conda command (which sub-repo) exactly you have to use
(which `-c ...` command you have to add to `conda install`).

e.g. for bioconda the curl is essential. But if you install your biggest
bioconductor (bioconda) packages, then their conda package will contain all those
necessities - and you don't have to care about them - installation will be done within
few minutes.
so try to install the biggest complex packages. IF there exist a conda package for those,
then most your installation will be done while the packages takes care
of all dependencies.

```
# in current env show all installed packages      $ conda list
# from outside any special environment, do:       $ conda list --name R361
# show all environment                            $ conda info --envs
# remove your environment                         $ conda remove -n R361

# all these commands are preactically all you need.
```

Answer (score 0):

I kept having these issues a few months ago. Literally the exact same error. I got around it by opening a terminal with admin privileges, launching R, and then updating. To do this just type

```
sudo -i R
```

Update as necessary. Some folks hate this, particularly if you don't trust or know the source, or if its a shared computer. I feel it is fine for my personal machine, so I do it all the time when updating bioconductor and related packages. I had to do it to correctly install GVIZ too.

Good luck.